# Formik, typescript, react native, get error properties dynamically

Tags: typescript, formik

In the code below, I Would like to wrap a form field with formik, and I dont know how can I get the errors object properties by name because of typescript error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FormikErrors'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FormikErrors'.ts(7053)

```
    interface AppFormProps{
    name: string
}


function AppFormField({name} : AppFormProps) {

    const {setFieldTouched, handleChange, errors} = useFormikContext();

    return (
        <>
          <AppTextInput
            //autoCapitalize="none"
            onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)} 
            //autoCorrect={false} 
            //icon="email"
            //keyboardType="email-address"
            onChangeText={handleChange(name)}
            //placeholder="Email" 
            //textContentType="emailAddress"
            />            
            <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]}/><-- ERROR IS HERE    
        </>
    );
}

export default AppFormField;
```

Thanks for your help!